# Calling an array that uses a global typescript file inside the html file for Angular 7+

Tags: html, arrays, angular, angular7

I'm having an issue calling an array inside my HTML file using a global.ts file for angular. When you use an array typically you give the element the array name then its sibling variable that is going to loop using this *ngFor="let element of elements". I'm already calling the global.ts file using the import and setting up the construct.

```html
<div ngxSlickItem *ngFor="let slide of slides" class="slide">
    <div class="slide-header">
        {{ slide.header }}
    </div>
    <div class="slide-paragraph">
        {{ slide.paragraph }}
    </div>
    <div class="slide-link">
        <a href="{{ slide.link }}">
            Learn More
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

But how would you then call an array using a global.ts file that uses an array? Normally using a simple variable in a global typescript file would look like this. I tried globals.slide.header but that does not seem right.

```html
<a class="nav-button btn btn-primary" href="#">
  {{globals.globalHrefLink}}
</a>
```

I have created this ts file:

```html
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class Globals {
    // Anchor Link
    globalHrefLink = 'new request';

    navitems = [
        {
            navTitle: 'home',
            routelink: '/home',
        },
        {
            navTitle: 'my request',
            routelink: '/myrequest',
        }
    ];
}
```

But how do I call it inside a header component?

```html
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto flex-nowrap" *ngFor="let navitem of navitems" class="navitem">
  <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link active" routerLink="{{navitem.routelink}}">{{navitem.navTitle}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Help appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you have to import global.ts in component.ts

```
import { AppGlobals } from '../app.globals';

export class Abc {
constructor(public globals: AppGlobals) {}

}
```

now you can use any variable of globals for example you have an elements array 
 in `globals.ts` like

```
elements = [ { NAME: 'test'} ];
```

```
<div *ngFor="let el of globals.elements">
  {{el.NAME}}
</div>
```

Comment: If it still gives you issues in the template set it to public.

Comment: how would you call that in html? {{parentarray.variable?}}

Comment: {{globals.variable}}

Comment: even if the array calls for the parent? like above slide.header? so I'm confused if you need to do globals.arrayparentname.variableinsidearry. Or will it recognize its in the array already therefore you dont need the parent array name.

Comment: i just added an example in answer let me know if that solves your problem

Comment: That is what I'm looking for! Thanks!